# Is there a way to construct a function which is it's own $n$'th derivative (cyclic)?

Tags: functions, derivatives

For $n$ equal to $1$ it's easy:

- $(e^x)'=e^x  $

for $n=4$ also:

- $\frac{d^4}{dx^4} \sin x = \sin x$

Now is there a way to construct a function where the $n$-th ($\in \mathbb{N}$) derivative is the first derivative which is the function again?

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f_n(x) = f_n(x)$$

---

Especial looking for big $n$ values. But example functions for (small) $n \neq \{1;4\}$ would also be interesting (write those in comments).

Comment: What I think you are asking is for general solutions to: $f^{(n)}(x)-f(x)=0$, which I believe would only give you exponential (and hyperbolic) or trig functions

Comment: The trivial $f(x)=0$ is satisfied for all $n$.  (:

Comment: @ChrisCulter oh, I searched for other but could not find that one. Only found one which is about not equal at any derivative. The linked is not exactly equal but very close to (different description and answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^k}{k!}}$$ works for $n=1$ and
$$ \mathrm{ch}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}} $$ works for $n=2$, one can think that
$$ f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!}} $$ works for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$.
In fact $f_n$ is well defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, thus
$$ f_n^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{(nk)(nk-1)\ldots(nk-k+1)\frac{x^{kn-k}}{(kn)!}}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{(k-1)n}}{((k-1)n)!}}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!}}=f_n(x) $$
$f_n$ is a solution to the problem and, for any $\omega\in\mathbb{U}_n$, $x\mapsto f_n(\omega x)$ works too.

Comment: Very nice by series!

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

Let $\omega$ be an (edit: principal) nth root of unity. That is, $\omega^n = 1$. Then $e^{\omega x}$ works.

---

Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: ty, for response. It's a solution as well but marked other because some more formula.

Answer (score 2):

We can think to $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$

$$f(x)=e^{\omega_0 x}$$

with $\omega_0=e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}\in\mathbb C $ principal root of unity.

Comment: ty, for response. It's a solution as well but marked other because some more formula.